# Win10 Full Screen Start Menu:Show BOTH All Apps List AND Tiles At The Same Time

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, fullscreen, tiles

I can see both the All Apps List and Tiles when the Start Menu is not in full screen mode, but when I switch to full screen view, Win10 forces the user to chose between viewing EITHER the tiles, OR the All Apps List, even though there is even MORE space available!  Is there any way to force Win10 to keep showing both simultaneously at the same time just like normal layout, except bigger, when switching the Start Menu to full screen?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not achieved. This is tablet mode UI by design for touch easily.